How to define a range to query on Sheet1 based on the value of a cell on Sheet2 and print to Sheet2
I have two sheets in excel.
On Sheet2, I have defined the starting row number to query a certain range on Sheet1.
How to copy the results of a query of Sheet1 to Sheet2 where the starting cell of the range is defined on Sheet2?
On Sheet2 in cell B20 I have entered the formula:
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C",$B$19)):$C$15002<5,0),0)
Which index's the range on the current sheet, but I want to index the range on Sheet1 with reference to the value in B19 on Sheet2 column C.

It looks like your formula is looking for the position of the first value that is below 5 in your defined range - =MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!C", $B$19, ":$C$15002"))<5,0),0)

Leaving the $C$15002 reference outside of the INDIRECT would result in the first part of the range reference referring to Sheet1, while the  :$C$15002 reference would still be referencing Sheet2.  That would mean having to write the formula as =MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!C",$B$19)):Sheet1!$C$15002<5,0),0).

Create for the INDIRECT function the range to lookup with the sheet name added like this.
For the CONCATENATE function it is simpler to join the whole range as text.
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!C",$B$19,":$C$15002"))<5,0),0)
